# Switch between 2g and 3g android terminal

Tags: android, terminal

Running CM 10.1 Nightly (no stable version yet) on Galaxy Note II (Intl), and the phone app won't switch between 2g/3g yet I'm trying to get the best battery performance using some tasker profiles and secure settings (pro) / Depp Sleep Inducer, and i need to be able to switch between 2g and 3g.

Is there any way of doing it via terminal?

Comment: So point me to the correct one, please

Comment: Well, I never said I know what is the right one, it is just not an development question.

Comment: What do you mean by _android terminal_?

Comment: Terminal Emulator https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=pt_BR

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you meant adb shell by *android terminal*. Also, note that you will need root access to perform the followings which set the network mode to 2G.

**1) Dump Settings provider's database.**

```
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/
```

**2) Set the value of "global" table's "preferred_network_mode" row to "1".**
First, check if the row exists:

```
sqlite3 settings.db
sqlite> SELECT * FROM global WHERE name='preferred_network_mode';
```

You should see something like `85|preferred_network_mode|0`. The row exists, set it to "1":

```
sqlite3 settings.db
sqlite> UPDATE global SET value='1' WHERE name='preferred_network_mode';
```

There will be no output if the row does not exist, so we need to insert it:

```
sqlite3 settings.db
sqlite> INSERT INTO global(name, value) VALUES('preferred_network_mode', '1');
```

**3) Push the updated database to target device.**

adb shell rm /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/*

adb push settings.db /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/

**4) Reboot the device.**

Comment: Is there any way for a non rooted device?